# Sci fi short story: inept king, tiny kingdom, time traveler secretly thwarting him

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, time-travel

I was searching for something other than this on the ["Stable Time Loop/Literature" page of tvtropes.org](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/StableTimeLoop/Literature), when I came across an entry with no title. I'm sure I've read the story, but there is no information listed other than a general plot outline (which is odd for the trope site):

> There was a short sci-fi story where a king, who is always coming up with crazy and unhelpful schemes to improve his small country discovers that a time traveler is helping his advisers to offset the impact of his schemes. He captures the time traveler and forces him to take them both into the future so he can see how things will turn out. They arrive in ten years in the future and the king sees that the country is prosperous beyond his wildest dreams, so he asks a passerby "What was the big change that brought about this golden age?" The passerby answers "It all turned around when the crazy king disappeared ten years ago and the advisers started ruling the nation". As the king wonders why he disappeared a decade ago, the time traveler shuts the door to his time machine, leaving the king in the future.

I seem to remember the king decreeing just ridiculous things... maybe only eating things of one color, things of that nature. The time traveler was definitely male and I believe reluctant to get involved initially. The forward travel time at the end may have been more than ten years. Also, it seems as if the king was surprised and embarrassed by the way the woman passerby was dressed, as if she were vulgar. The story was more lighthearted than much of the intense "Aesop" type sci fi regarding time travel.

I read a LOT, so it's hard for me to pin down. Regarding my reading habits, it could be Philip K Dick, Robert Heinlein, Isaac Asimov, Arthur C Clarke, or from Gardner Dozois's Years Best Science Fiction, which I will be scouring shortly. I've already been cross-referencing the books I own with Google books for specific key words, but we all know how reliable that can be.

I also have this query listed on [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/tipofmytongue/comments/y3ht4q/tomtscifishort_story/).

10-19-22: I have cross-referenced all short stories by Isaac Asimov and Robert Heinlein and have eliminated them as prospective sources.

10-20-22: I believe this country was landlocked and the king wouldn't permit any trade or communication with surrounding countries, possibly due to some religious superstition. He would not allow any technological advances, and this explains how the country was able to change so drastically in only ten years: once he was gone, the advisors began relations with their neighbors.
I believe there were moving sidewalks with various lanes of differing speeds.
The king's tower from which he governed has been preserved (though modernized) and it is from the top that his three advisors now rule.

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: You might want to mention that this question is cross-posted here; https://www.reddit.com/r/tipofmytongue/comments/y3ht4q/tomtscifishort_story/, in case someone over there comes up with the answer

Comment: This almost sounds like one of Larry Niven's Svetz stories.

Comment: @ZeissIkon To my regret I have read those, and this isn't one of them.

Comment: Oh well, worth a try.

Comment: Thanks for trying. I haven't read those Niven stories. Once I scratch this itch, I'll embark on those.

Comment: @DavidW You regret having read them? If they are that bad, why didn't you stop after one or two?

Comment: @user14111 In those days I was unable to put down a book before I finished it.  I mean I read all the way through *Battlefield Earth* FFS.  Not to mention other gems such as *NYPD 2025* and so many Piers Anthony books, that my aunt kept buying for me.

Comment: @DavidW, I can relate. While studying early Gothic literature (which later helped spawn the sci-fi genre), I waded through all ~700 pages of Ann Radcliffe's "The Mysteries of Udolpho". If you haven't read it, don't.

Comment: @DavidW Is *Battlefield Earth* really bad? Never looked at it, but I enjoyed some of Hubbard's Golden Age yarns, such as "To the Stars".

Comment: @user14111 Oh yeah, it's bad.  It's one of those books that gets worse the more you think about it.  It might have been an average 1940s planetary romance, but it's about 800 pages too long for that.  A decent editor could have trimmed more than half of it, and it still wouldn't have been worth reading.

Comment: This does sound like something Piers Anthony would write, but a quick search didn't find any matches.  Someone could easily think Battlefield Earth is a spoof.  As a spoof, intentional or not, it's pretty hilarious.  Way, way, way too long though.

Comment: @user14111 It is real bad. Some 20 years ago I gave it a try. "Surely it couldn't be that bad?" Well, it was worse. I gave up in disgust after about 30 pages and threw it in the fireplace. Only book I ever felt a need to burn...